# Calling an API asynchronously and parsing JSON

Tags: c#, json, swift, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I come from an iOS (Swift) background. In one of my Swift apps, I have this class that calls an API. I'm trying to port it to C# (Windows Form application) but I'm hitting several snags. First here's the Swift code. Nothing fancy. One method does a POST request to login to the API and the other function executes a GET method to retrieve the JSON response for a user profile. Both these methods are asynchronous.

```
import Foundation

class API {

    private let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    private let baseURL = "https://www.example.com/api/"

    func login(userID userID: String, password: String, completion: (error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        let url = NSURL(string: baseURL + "login")!
        let params = ["username": userID, "password": password]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.encodeParameters(params) // encodeParameters is an extension method
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    completion(error: error)
                } else {
                    completion(error: nil)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    func fetchUser(completion: (user: User?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        let url = NSURL(string: baseURL + "profile")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(user: nil, error: error)
            } else {
                // Parsing JSON
                var jsonDict = [String: AnyObject]()
                do {
                    jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
                } catch {
                    print("Error occurred parsing data: \(error)")
                    completion(user: nil, error: error)
                }

                let user = User()
                user.name = jsonDict["name"] as! String
                user.age = jsonDict["age"] as! Int

                completion(user: user, error: nil)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt to convert this to C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace MyTrayApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string baseURL = "https://www.example.com/api/";


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await login("myusername", "mypassword");
            await fetchUser();
        }

        async Task login(string userID, string password)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "username", userID },
                    { "password", password }
                };

                var encodedParameters = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("login", encodedParameters);
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
        }

        async Task fetchUser()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
                var response = await client.GetAsync("profile");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString.ToCharArray()), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
                var root = XElement.Load(jsonReader);
                Console.WriteLine(root.XPathSelectElement("//name").Value);

                //Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the problems I'm having.

1. In my Swift methods, they have completion handlers. How can I do the same in C#?
2. In Swift, you get an `NSData` object and you can pass it to `NSJSONSerialization` to create a JSON object. In my current implementation, I get an XML exception at `XElement.Load(jsonReader);`. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this even. I found tons of different solutions here on SO. But some are for Metro apps, some are for web it's all too overwhelming. Also most solutions are on using third-party libraries like JSON.NET. I'm trying to achieve this without third-party libraries.

Comment: To pile on what Todd said, most people are just using JSON.NET as the defacto .net parser.  However, if a 3rd party dependency is really a blocker, some people just inline the source code from SimpleJSON http://simplejson.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: Also, it is recommended to reuse instances of HttpClient, so just declare it as a field and dispose it when you are done with it.  This will give better performance because it will allow you to reuse HTTP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Swift methods, they have completion handlers. How can I do the
>   same in C#?

The point of wiring up a completion handler is so that you don't tie up a thread while waiting for the HTTP call to complete. The beauty of `async`/`await` is that you don't have to do this in C#. The `await` keyword instructs the compiler to literally rewrite the rest of the method as a callback. The current thread is freed as soon as `await` is encountered, preventing your UI from freezing up. You have written your async code correctly; it will behave asynchronously even though it looks synchronous.

Your second question is a bit broad, but I will make 2 suggestions:

1. Don't use `XElement` when dealing with JSON data. That part of an Microsoft's [XML parsing library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (one of them) and has nothing to do with JSON.
2. I'm not sure why achieving this without a 3rd-party library is important. I know people have their reasons, but Json.NET in particular has become so popular and ubiquitous that Microsoft itself has baked it into their ASP.NET MVC and Web API frameworks. That said, if you must avoid it, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) is how you would deserialize JSON using only Microsoft libraries.